# Rust concurrency question with SyncSender

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and trying to understand the Dining Philosopher code here :

https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/exercises/day-4/solutions-morning.html

By the time the execution reaches the following lines in the main thread, isn't it possible that none of the spawned threads have started executing their logic, resulting in nothing in 'rx' and the program simply quitting?

```
for thought in rx {
        println!("{}", thought);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When iterating over a channel, it internally calls [Receiver::recv](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv), where the documentation specifies

> This function will always block the current thread if there is no data available and it’s possible for more data to be sent (at least one sender still exists). Once a message is sent to the corresponding Sender (or SyncSender), this receiver will wake up and return that message.

So the receiver will block until it has data avalible, or all the senders have been dropped.

Comment: thanks, so in the case of Async Sender, this wont happen? In that case, we need some kind of fork-join mechanism ?

Comment: As in the async version of channel like in tokio? You get the same results, usage is just slightly different. `while let Some(data) = rx.recv().await{}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, execution can reach `for thought in rx { ... }` before the threads have even started. However, this will still work because iterating over a [`Receiver`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) will wait until there is a message and will only stop if all [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html)s have been destroyed (ergo it is no longer possible to receive any messages).